# Has something replaced BeanItemContainer in Vaadin 8?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-charts

I downloaded a copy of the **vaadin-charts-video** example project from GitHub (https://github.com/vaadin-miki/vaadin-charts-video) to get a feel for how **Vaadin charts** are supposed to be implemented. However that project, and most of the available demo code/projects I have found seem to be written using **Vaadin 7** and prior coding conventions. I am jumping in with **Vaadin 8.0.5** (and JDK8)...

These errors are appearing when running Maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project intro-video: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/dev/vaadin/vaadin-charts-video/intro-video/src/main/java/org/vaadin/miki/charts/intro/IntroChartsUI.java:[19,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BeanItemContainer
[ERROR] location: package com.vaadin.data.util
[ERROR] /C:/Users/dev/vaadin/vaadin-charts-video/intro-video/src/main/java/org/vaadin/miki/charts/intro/IntroChartsUI.java:[54,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BeanItemContainer
[ERROR] location: class org.vaadin.miki.charts.intro.IntroChartsUI
[ERROR] /C:/Users/dev/vaadin/vaadin-charts-video/intro-video/src/main/java/org/vaadin/miki/charts/intro/IntroChartsUI.java:[54,62] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BeanItemContainer
[ERROR] location: class org.vaadin.miki.charts.intro.IntroChartsUI
```

Can anyone tell me, **has BeanItemContainer been replaced?** And if so, by what?

For example, see Line 54 of https://github.com/vaadin-miki/vaadin-charts-video/blob/master/intro-video/src/main/java/org/vaadin/miki/charts/intro/IntroChartsUI.java
`BeanItemContainer<BookPrice> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(BookPrice.class, prices);`

And if that doesn't appear to be the issue to more experienced eyes, please let me know what is...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `Container` is dead

Vaadin 8 no longer has `Container`. The [Vaadin data model](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-overview.html) has been largely simplified. Basically, there is no data model anymore. There are just data providers for the various elements. What you want to look into is [`DataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html), as it largely replaces [`Container`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.9/com/vaadin/data/Container.html).

A short introduction to the changes is here: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-framework-8-comes-with-java-8-native-apis

Generally, for most uses you will either use `setItems` directly or use a [`ListDataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html).

## Long live `Container`

To ease migrating your existing Vaadin 7 app to Vaadin 8, you can use the Vaadin 7 compatibility layer. This includes the [old Vaadin data model](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/datamodel/datamodel-overview.html) and `Container`. Move to Vaadin 8 while making very few changes to your existing code base.

See:

- One-minute video, [Migrating to Vaadin 8](https://youtu.be/6ZoRun38Z5w)
- Vaadin.com documentation, [Migration from Framework 7 to Framework 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html).
- [Migrating to Vaadin 8](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-to-vaadin-8) article by Thomas Kratz.

Answer (score 4):

As it has already been correctly said: Container is no longer.

You can directly set the items at the UI element like

```
grid.setItems(books);
```

This will create a ListDataProvider under the cover.

If you want to change the items (add/remove) to the UI element without setting the items anew then you can create the ListDataProvider yourself like this:

```
List<Book> data = new Arraylist<>(getBooks());
ListDataProvider<Book> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(data);
Grid<Book> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
```

If you later want to work on the items you just work on the list

```
data.add(newBook);
```

and call

```
dataProvider.refreshAll();
```

or

```
dataProvider.refreshItem(book);
```

If the attributes of the items have changed you probably need to call

```
grid.markAsDirty();
```

so that the grid will fetch the new data from the items.